# How to understand Google Cloud Datastream UNSUPPORTED_EVENTS_DISCARDED

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, cdc, google-datastream

Is there a way to get more detail about unsupported events in google cloud datastream?

I am running a datastream from MySQL and have a few `UNSUPPORTED_EVENTS_DISCARDED` and I would like to understand what these events are.

In the logs explorer detail is limited to something like following:

```
message: "Discarded 1 unsupported events with reason code: MYSQL_UNKNOWN_ERROR. Latest discarded event details: An unexpected error occurred while fetching log: mysql-bin.013919, log_pos: 91832523."
event_code: "UNSUPPORTED_EVENTS_DISCARDED"
```

Answer (score 4):

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/datastream/docs/sources#mysqlknownlimitations) are some limitations regarding datastream/mysql:

- Events have a size limitation of 3 MB
- Tables that have more than 100 million rows
- Not all changes to the source schema can be detected automatically

I suspect that some of the data that you are fetching hits the limitation and returns the error. I recommend to review the document with the limitation and make sure all the data can be fetched.